# Need to Edit Javascript to Have Container Dynamically Expand

Tags: javascript

http://iamced.net/2014-1/timeline/

I have a content container that is not resizing, to accommodate whatever amount of text that is placed in it.  Dlaxar has pointed me in the right direction, by calling my attention to the container 'max-height' being set.

```
.content {
 max-height: 0;
 padding: 50px 20px 0;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
 position: relative;
}

.content p {
 max-height: 0;
 color: transparent;
 text-align: justify;
 word-break: break-word;
 hyphens: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

I took the max-height lines completely out,
but that didn't change anything. I set the 
value to 'false', but that didn't help 
either.  How should I properly 'un-set'
the max-height?

Comment: Is there a reason you've set `max-height` on the container element. This keeps the container from growing as big as it needs to be.

Comment: Dlaxar: so how do I rectify that situation. I've a) removed the max-height and b) set it to false but nothing changed.  What's the proper way to deal with that max-height situation?

Answer (score 0):

the offending rule in CSS is in this block

```
.radio:checked ~ .content {
  max-height: 180px;
  border-color: #eee9dc;
  margin-right: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  transition: max-height 0.4s linear, border-color 0.5s linear, -webkit-transform 0.2s  linear;
 }
```

You have a general sibling selector ' ~ ' that essentially says anytime you have a radio button in selected state find a sibling with class content and set the maximum height at 180px.

You need to find out where that rule is set and either remove it completely or maybe do an overflow scroll or set the min height. The page seems to have other problems, but as far as the overlap is concerned this is where the issue is.

Hope that helps

Comment: Here's a better rendering of the code: http://iamced.net/2014-1/timeline/ Some how I jacked up the other version of it. (Also forgot I had made a person entry, and them posted it on SO.  Genius!!!)

Comment: So setting the minimum height will effect establish no maximum height?